# How to select html element with XPATH based on inner element?

Tags: html, xpath

In a html document I have the following situation:

```
...
<div data-v-16ed3604="" class="ivu-select ivu-select-single ivu-select-small">
  <div tabindex="0" class="ivu-select-selection xh-highlight">
    <input type="hidden" value=""> 
    <div> 
      <span class="ivu-select-placeholder">Prop</span> 
      ...

<div data-v-16ed3604="" class="ivu-select ivu-select-single ivu-select-small">
  <div tabindex="0" class="ivu-select-selection xh-highlight">
    <input type="hidden" value=""> 
    <div> 
      <span class="ivu-select-placeholder">Something else</span> 
      ...
```

Here I want to select the *first* `div` element with class `ivu-select-selection` (second row). The XPATH to get the elements with class `ivu-select-selection` is

```
//div[@class="ivu-select-selection"]
```

but it selects **two** elements. I just want the element which has the `span` element with the text `Prop` below it. I want to select just the *second row* of this html example. .

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below XPath to get required output:

```
//div[@class="ivu-select-selection" and .//span="Prop"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
//span[contains(text(),'Prop')]//ancestor::div[@class='ivu-select-selection xh-highlight']
```

Comment: But don't I select the element `<span class="ivu-select-placeholder">Prop</span>` with that expression? That is not what I want. I want to select the SECOND row of my html example...

Comment: Can you please share next line of HTML after span , Which you want to target

Comment: Could you please mention, what is your second row as according to your example.  "I want to select the SECOND row of my html example."  I am still not getting, what is your actual target.

Comment: Please make sure what you want to target, As according to your question its look like you want to target <span> with text of Prop. Please forget that you can achieve it only through <div> which you have mentioned. Try with the answer you will get desired result for "Prop".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174215/discussion-between-alex-and-ishita-shah).

Comment: I want to target the second row.